# Exchange NZ drivers licence for a UK licence

Tags: driving-license

Does anyone know if you can exchange a New Zealand learners license for the UK equivalent and what that would be? TIA

Comment: The UK government pages (starting with: https://www.gov.uk/exchange-foreign-driving-licence) on exchanging licenses don't mention "learner," "provisional," or "limited" licenses. Thus, I think you'd have to ask DVLA whether such licenses can be exchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes sense to "exchange" to get a provisional licence. There are no qualifications required to get a UK provisional licence (other than self-certification that your corrected vision is good enough). I understand that in NZ, you need to pass a test to get a learner licence, but this isn't the case in the UK. So you can just [apply for a provisional licence](https://www.gov.uk/apply-first-provisional-driving-licence).